# ImageAI Object detection with prediction training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imageai

I have successfully trained a predictor model - so with no labels using `ModelTraining` class.

Currently, I can use `CustomImagePrediction.predictImage()` to return a value of what it thinks is in the picture.

I want to be able to detect the location of the object in the image, not just what it thinks it is. This functionality is in `CustomObjectDetection` but this is obviously a different class (gives a no label error as it requires the other training method, with the labels).

Is it possible to achieve this with a predictor model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, location of objects is only possible with detection because it works on coordinates (bounding box), label error means you have to annotate your dataset.